# Как создать файл и папки по пути к нему

Tags: c++, файлы, c++11, файловая-система, кроссплатформенность

Есть файл:

```
const std::string logFile = "log.txt";
```

Есть путь к нему:

```
const std::string logPath = "Logs/tmp/"
```

Как создать папки по пути к файлу, если из нет.
А также как создать файл, если его нет, а если есть - дописать в его конец.

Также, поскольку я использую C++11, я не могу использовать `std::filesystem` или `std::experimental`.

---

**У меня сейчас так**:

```
#ifndef DEBUGGER_HPP
#define DEBUGGER_HPP

#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>



#include "../Main/Settings.hpp"

namespace Debugger
{

    //
    void PrintDebug(const std::string input){
        if (Settings::settings_DebugMode >= 2){

            // Add current datetime
            auto seconds = time(NULL);
            auto* timeinfo = localtime(&seconds);

            std::string result = "[DEBUG] [ ";
            result += asctime(timeinfo);
            result.erase(result.rfind('\n'), 1);
            result += " ] " + input + '\n';

            if (Settings::settings_LogPath == "console"){
                std::cout << result;
            } else {

                // Create folder if it doesn't exist
                for(std::string::size_type pos = 0; (pos = Settings::settings_LogPath.find('/',pos+1)) != std::string::npos;)
                {
                    mkdir(Settings::settings_LogPath.substr(0,pos).c_str());
                }

                // Create logFile
                std::ofstream logFile;
                logFile.open("log.txt", std::ios::app);
                logFile << result;
                logFile.close();
            }
        }
    }

}

#endif // DEBUGGER_HPP
```

Comment: Вы можете разбить путь на составляющие и рекурсивно создать каталоги, начиная с корневого, проверяя есть ли он уже.

Comment: @timur я же поставил тег "кроссплатформенность"

Comment: [boost filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)?

Comment: Если используется Qt, то папки можно создать через [QDir::mkpath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath) а наличие проверить через `QFile::exists`

Comment: @MaximTimakov нет, в этот раз - это курсач, поэтому без qt

Comment: Используйте [Boost.Filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) или другую специальную библиотеку, если нет доступа к `<filesystem>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грустно, что нельзя использовать что-то кроме С++11.

Тогда посоветовал бы разбивать путь на составные куски по слешу, и использовать [`mkdir`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/mkdir#:%7E:text=int%20mkdir(const%20char%20*path)&text=%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20mkdir()%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3,%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20ENOENT%20(%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C).) для покусочного :) создания пути (насколько я помню, длинные вложенные каталоги он не создает - типа, `log/test` не создаст, если нет `log`).

Ну, а когда путь есть и вы в этом убедились - обычные функции для работы с файлами. Например,

```
ofstream of("data",ios::app);
of << "random string" << endl;
```

Если файла нет - он будет создан, если есть - будет выполнена дозапись в его конец.

Разбивать на части? Да хоть так:

```
string logPath = "My/Long/Log/path/";
for(string::size_type pos = 0; (pos = logPath.find('/',pos+1)) != string::npos;)
{
    cout << "mkdir(" << logPath.substr(0,pos).c_str() << ")\n";
}
```

Понятно, что вместо вывода строки надо использовать `mkdir`. Рекурсия особо не нужна, если каталог уже есть - попытка его создать к неприятностям не приведет...

Comment: Если можно - приведите код разбиения по слешу рекурсивное

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: mkdir - это работает только в Windows, а мне нужно кроссплатформенно

Comment: `mkdir` - это не Windows, это POSIX, не верится, что функции нет там, где есть каталоги :)

Comment: в Linux Mint gcc такого нет

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, linux - [man 2 mkdir](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=mkdir&category=2&russian=2), windows [mkdir](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkdir?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @MaximTimakov Да не убедите вы его, оставьте... Не подключил, вероятно, нужный заголовок, или еще что, но виноватым будете вы - что обманываете :)

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Как раз наоборот, на Windows mkdir не работает надлежащим образом, так как пути могут содержать юникод или когда нужны ACL.

Comment: https://ideone.com/qkq5bu

Comment: #include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

Comment: Спасибо.........

Answer (score 4):

Отвечу по поводу создания нескольких директорий, вложенных друг в друга, à la `mkdir -p`. Это популярный запрос, как выяснилось. Есть программы, написанные для создания директорий рекурсивно, например здесь: http://mylinuxtechcorner.blogspot.com/2012/09/c-version-for-mkdir-p.html

Привожу код оттуда:

```
int createPath( mode_t mode, const std::string& rootPath, std::string& path )
{
    struct stat st;

    for( std::string::iterator iter = path.begin() ; iter != path.end(); )
    {
         std::string::iterator newIter = std::find( iter, path.end(), '/' );
         std::string newPath = rootPath + "/" + std::string( path.begin(), newIter);

         if( stat( newPath.c_str(), &st) != 0)
         {           
             if( mkdir( newPath.c_str(), mode) != 0 && errno != EEXIST )
             {
                std::cout << "cannot create folder [" << newPath << "] : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                return -1;
             }
         }
         else
            if( !S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) )
             {
                 errno = ENOTDIR;
                 std:: cout << "path [" << newPath << "] not a dir " << std::endl;
                 return -1;
             }
             else
                 std::cout << "path [" << newPath << "] already exists " << std::endl;


         iter = newIter;
         if( newIter != path.end() )
             ++ iter;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {

    std::string path = "ionut/AAA/BBB";
    createPath(0777, "/home", path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему явно *итеративный* способ называют *рекурсивным*?

Comment: @avp алгоритм итеративный, но применительно к директориям говорят же recursive, например man ls(1): -R: Recursively list subdirectories encountered.

Comment: Также такое можно сказать про find, grep ... Но это **обход дерева рекурсивный**. В данном случае же, очевидно, строго линейная итерация по заданным компонентам пути

Comment: @avp No problem, изменил формулировку.